# oracle to sql sever query translation

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can someone help me to translate the below Oracle query to SQL SERVER syntax ?

```
with cte as(
select to_date('05-05-2022','mm-dd-yyyy') as eff_dt,
to_date('12-31-2022', 'mm-dd-yyyy') as exp_dt from dual
)

select eff,exp,round(months_between(exp,eff)) from(
select case when level = 1 then eff_dt
else add_months(trunc(eff_dt,'Y'),12*(level-1)) end as eff,
last_day(add_months(trunc(eff_dt,'Y'),12*level-1)) as exp
from 
cte connect by level<=extract(year from exp_dt)-extract(year from eff_dt)+1)
;
```

Comment: This is a recursive query. Do you know how to write recursive queries in SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm new to SQL SERVER

Comment: Where, exactly do you need help? What is your current attempt? Why isn't it working? [so] isn't a free translation service; you need to do the research yourself and attempt to translate the query. When you get stuck you can then explain exactly where you did and why, showing your current attempt.

Answer (score -1):

**Learn standard SQL language**. MS SQL Server use standard SQL while Oracle has always wanted to go on its own dialect, despite the fact that Jim Melton, the technical mentor of Oracle was the reporter of the standard ISO SQL !

Well in any good book, you will find that CAST is the normative function to CAST... and CTE (Common Table Expression) is the normative construction to write recursive queries.

On this topic, you can use the paper I wrote many years ago : "[Recursive Queries in SQL:1999 and SQL Server 2005](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/recursive-queries-in-sql1999-and-sql-server-2005)"